# Rspec takes too long to load

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, datamapper, rspec-rails

I am using Rspec with my Rails 3.2.11 app. I have installed and set up spork.
I use datamapper as ORM.

Yet when spork is running, a running a single test takes more than a minute. 
Even if the test being run is empty. Something is surely wrong. But I cannot figure 
out what exactly.

My test_spec is as this:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "cancan/matchers"

describe User do
end
```

My spec helper file can be found here: https://gist.github.com/4593609

When I time the rspec:

```
➜  books git:(dev) ✗ time rspec --drb spec/models/test_spec.rb
No examples found.


Finished in 1 minute 51.08 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
rspec --drb spec/models/test_spec.rb  1.49s user 0.04s system 1% cpu 1:52.94 total
```

Spork Log:

```
➜  books git:(dev) ✗ spork
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Running tests with args ["spec/models/test_spec.rb"]...
Done.

Running tests with args ["spec/models/test_spec.rb"]...
Done.
```

This is for an empty spec. It takes more time for specs with lots of examples.
What can be taking so long for it to run ?

Comment: are you connected to a remote database ? Does the database tables have too many columns ? I think both of these are true in your case :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. The problem was in 
my spec_helper file.

```
 config.before(:suite) {
   DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
 }
```

Because of these configs, Datamapper was trying to autoupgrade
each time I ran the test. On commenting this config, spec started
working normally even when spork is not running.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your test.log when running the tests , probably the database setup is done for every test and it takes up the time.

`tail -f log/test.log` 
when running the test

Comment: I tailed the test.log file and I was shocked. A "SHOW COLUMNS FROM 'model' LIKE 'attribute' " query runs for each and every model and its attributes.

What should I do to prevent this ?

Comment: which mode you are running the server?

Comment: @yashir Can you please elaborate ?